# etale fundamental group of a product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, galois-theory, schemes, fundamental-groups

Let $X,Y$ be noetherian connected schemes over an algebraically closed field $k$ and let $\overline{x},\overline{y}$ be geometric points on them. There is a canonical homomorphism

$\pi_1(X \times Y,(\overline{x},\overline{y})) \to \pi_1(X,\overline{x}) \times \pi_1(Y,\overline{y})$

This is known to be an isomorphism when $X$ or $Y$ is proper and geometrically integer. This follows from a more general exact sequence in $\pi_1$ related to a proper flat morphism with geometrically integer fibers.

**Question 1.** Is there a more direct proof of this isomorphism? The corresponding isomorphism in topology is trivial, is it really that difficult in algebraic geometry?

**Question 2.** Is the assumption on $X$ or $Y$ really needed? If yes, can you give an easy counterexample for the general case?

Comment: The corresponding isomorphism in topology is only trivial if you define $\pi_1$ in terms of maps from the circle. If you define $\pi_1$ directly in terms of covering spaces, is it still trivial?

Comment: @Qiaochu: Which definition in terms of covering spaces do you mean?

Comment: A late answer. But I guess Qiaochu means that one can define $\pi_1$ to be the group of automorphisms of the universal cover that respect the covering map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof of the isomorphism is not so hard in SGA 1 X 1.7.

A counterexample when none of $X, Y$ is proper is given in SGA 1 X 1.10 with $X=Y$ equal to the affine line over a field of positive characteristic.